# Утроба, требуха — этимология

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "утроба" и "требуха" к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 1):

Вопросы этимологии часто сложны, и порой дать однозначный, уверенный ответ на вопрос, однокоренные ли это слова или нет, невозможно. Мое личное мнение, что они не однокоренные.

Обоснование
П. Я. Черных во 2-м томе своего историко-этимологического словаря (8-е изд., стереотип., М.: Русский язык - Медиа, 2007, с. 296) пишет о слове "утроба":
"Утроба - внутренности, чрево, живот... болг. утроба, утробный, словен. votroba; чеш. и словац. utroba; польск. watroba - печень; н.-луж. wutsoba - сердце... Др.-рус. (с X-XI в.) утроба - чрево, желудок, внутренности... ср. утрь - внутренность (Срезневский, III, 1315-1316). Общеславянская основа *qtroba. Общеславянский корень *qtr, суф. -ob(a). На русской почве связано с такими словами, как нутро, где корень утр- < *qtr-, внутри, внутрь. Проще говоря, древний корень этого слова - *qtr-. Происхождение слова "требуха" неясно, но оно в древности, согласно современным данным, имело другой корень.
См.: 1. "Требу́х "обжора, жадный человек", укр. трибу́х "внутренности, требуха", блр. требу́х, др.-русск., русск.-цслав. трибухъ – то же (см. Срезн. III, 993), болг. търбу́х "желудок, живот", сербохорв. тр̀бух "брюхо", словен. trẹ́buh – то же, чеш. třebucha, terbuch "брюхо", польск. trybuch, terbuch, telbuch. Праслав. праформа реконструируется с трудом. Если исходить из *trьbuхъ, то тогда можно сближать с *trь- (см. тре-) и к. слова бу́хнуть, на-буха́ть. Торбьёрнссон (2, 84) считает исходным *terb- и сравнивает с укр. те́реб "брюхо", теребух "обжора"; зап. формы на ter- остаются неясными и в этом случае.
(Источник - https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-13777.htm)
2. требуха
Общеслав. Происхождение неясно. Наиболее предпочтительным представляется объяснение слова как суф. производного (суф. -ух-) от той же основы (*terb-), что укр. тереб «брюхо», трибух «внутренности», сербохорв. трбух «живот, требуха», теребить, диал. требить «очищать негодное», «истреблять». В таком случае требуха буквально — «желудок с кишками, внутренности, от которых очищается туша забитой скотины».
(Источник - http://endic.ru/rusethy/Trebuha-4643.html)

Таким образом, древний корень слова "требуха" - *terb-. Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что этимологически эти слова не однокоренные, хотя значения их пересекались в древности (и то, и другое слово обозначало внутренности).